Angular website kt-aside shifting elements to the right on initial load, but not after
I have a bit of a doozy for you here.
So I have a span that gets displayed and positioned on an HTML Canvas element when certain elements on the canvas are hovered over, and hidden when they are not. This is done using a listener for mousemove on the canvas and setting the span's css elements for display, top, and left. This usually works perfectly.
fromEvent(canvasEl, "mousemove").subscribe((e: TouchEvent) => {
        const XY = this.computeXY(canvasEl, e, this.scale, this.translatePos);
        let pathIndex = this.isPointInPaths(XY.x, XY.y);
        if (Number.isInteger(pathIndex)) {
            this.updateCanvasTooltip(true, e['clientX'], e['clientY'], this.paths[pathIndex].Name); ...

private updateCanvasTooltip(display, x = 0, y = 0, Name = "") {
    if (display) {
        y = y + 20;
        this.tooltipSpan.style.display = "block";
        this.tooltipSpan.style.top = y + "px";
        this.tooltipSpan.style.left = x + "px";
        this.tooltipSpan.textContent = Name;
    } else {
        this.tooltipSpan.style.display = "none";
    }
}

This code all works perfectly fine for me, and the display works great as long as I've recently refreshed the page.

The issue that I am having is that on initial load of the page, regardless of if it's in production or my development environment, the span gets shifted over by the width of the kt-aside bar on the left.

I'm certain that it has something to do with the kt-aside, as if the bar is collapsed then it only is shifted over by the width of the shrunken bar

Once I refresh the page it works perfectly fine.
I've compared the CSS and attributes of the kt-aside bar before and after refresh, and they seem identical. I also checked the x and y that I set the top and left to before and after load, and the coordinates are the same both times
It honestly seems like where the page considers '0' to be before the page is refreshed is where the kt-aside ends, and after refresh its the actual leftmost side of the page. One of the things I checked for was to see if the z-index or something along those lines caused the aside to be considered on a higher level than the canvas after refresh, but I didn't see anything that would cause this
I still think its some kind of angular setting and I think I'm on to something with the level, but I can't find anything within the code itself, any idea what the issue might be?
